# Odoo reports: No module named report

Tags: report, odoo

In OpenERP 7, I used to create reports in (report) directory and import the directory in the `__init__.py` using the statement: `import report` and it worked fine.

In Odoo 8, when I tried to install the same module that worked on OpenERP 7 I got the error message: `No module named report`

Is Odoo 8 not allowing to import directories? How to solve this?

Comment: did you tried changing the folder / directory name?

Comment: No I didn't. Will this make any difference?

Comment: is there report named folder inside your module and report folder having an __init__.py file?then it should be working

Comment: Yes it should, and that's was the case with version 7. But it stopped working when I tried to install it on Odoo 8 !

Comment: Reporting engine have changed for Odoo 8. If you try to install version 7 module that has old reports, it might not let you do that, so this might be related.

Answer (score 0):

because obviously you can't use modules across different versions of Odoo "OpenErp",
the migration process however has it's own set of procedures it maybe become so hard to migrate between versions but it still possible.